# Does regret change when the loss function is dependent on the previous predictions?

Tags: online-algorithms, upper-bound

The loss function of each expert in the expert advice problem(or any online learning problem) depends on the time($t$)  and expert advice at that time($f_{t}(i)$).
suppose in this problem, loss function depends on the previous prediction of the algorithm.
$$ l _{t} (i) = p_{1} p_{2} \cdots p_{t-1}f_{t}(i)$$
such that $p$ show prediction of algorithm.

Does the upper bound of regret change?

Comment: Have you tried working through the standard proof to see if it breaks down in this setting?  Have you tried to work through some simple examples?

Comment: I see the multiplicative weights update algorithm and proof it.  but I  like to know Does dependency does not affect the calculation or definition of regret?